# Distribution of a function of Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Q) Let $W = \int_{0}^{t}B_sds$, $B$ is a Brownian motion. Find $EW$ and $EW^2$.

My attempt: 
$B_s \sim N(0,s) $

$$W = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}ds , EW = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}ds)dx$$

I am not sure how to find $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}ds$? Integration by reduction makes sense in the case of $\int x^ne^{ax}dx$ if n is a positive integer, where in if $I_n = \int x^ne^{ax}dx$, then $I_n = \frac{1}{a}(e^{ax}x^{n+1}-aI_{n-1})$, $I_0$ can be computed and all $I_n$ recursively.

Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: $W= \int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}} e^{-x^2/2s} \, ds$ **fails** to hold; this is already indicated by the fact that a) the left-hand side is random but the right-hand side is not, b) the left-hand side can take negative values but the right-hand side cannot. In order to calculate the mean you have to apply Fubini's theorem. For more details see one of the many duplicate questions e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075464/36150), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304164/36150) or [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time)

Comment: $EW=\int_0^{t}EB_s ds=\int_0^{t} 0ds=0$.

Comment: @saz By $W = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}e^{-x^2/2s}$, I was thinking of density of $W$ as the integral. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward if you can use Ito's Lemma and Ito's Isometry.

If you are allowed to use those result than $\mathbb E W$ and $\mathbb E W^2$ can be computed in the following way. Start by applying Ito's Lemma to $t B_t$ to obtain

$$ d(tB_t)=B_tdt+tdB_t$$

From this we obtain that

$$\int_0^t B_sds = t B_t - \int_0^t s dB_s$$
It is immediate form the above expression that $\mathbb E W =0$. To compute $\mathbb E W^2$, note that the expression for $\int_0^t B_sds$ derived above implies that 
$$ \int_0^t B_sds = t \int_0^t \left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)dB_s$$ Therefore,
$$ \mathbb E W^2 = t^2\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^t \left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)dB_s\right)^2\right] = t^2 \int_0^t \left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)^2ds$$ by Ito Isometry. Computing this integral, we note that $\mathbb E W^2=t^3/3$.